# Xamarin Android Toolbar Spinner

Tags: android, xamarin, android-spinner, android-toolbar

My Toolbar spinner is not showing the text. The adapter is filled up, but only the arrow is showing up.

```
var myList = Task.Run(() => new MyListService().Get(Convert.ToInt32(new LoginApplication().UserName), token)).Result.OrderBy(x => x.Vencimento).ToArray();
```

[Edit] MyList Contains Elements while debugging

`var adapter = new MyAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.simple_icon_spinner_dropdown_item, carteirinhas);`

`toolbarSpinner.Adapter = adapter;`

-- EDIT -- Added MyAdapter CustomAdapter Class

```
public class MyAdapter : ArrayAdapter<MyModel>{
        private Context _context;
        private MyModel[] _values;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, MyMdoel[] values) : base(context, textViewResourceId)
        {
            _context = context;
            _values = values;
        }

        public int Count()
        {
            return _values.Length;
        }

        public MyModel GetItem(int position)
        {
            return _values[position];
        }

        public long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            TextView label = new TextView(_context);
            label.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
            label.SetText(_values[position].Curso.NomeCurso, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            return label;
        }

        public override View GetDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            TextView label = new TextView(_context);
            label.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
            label.SetText(_values[position].Curso.NomeCurso, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            return label;
        }
    }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does myList have anything in it when you step through with the debugger?

Comment: Could you please post the codes of your custom adapter?

Comment: Added CustomAdapter and myList contains 2 elements in my case.